# Ionic initialize ng-model for range slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently working on an Ionic project where you can search for some used cars.
The app also includes some filters with range sliders to set the values as follows:

[image]

My problem now is that the filters are set to a default value on startup which would be:

user_settings = {price: {min: 0, max: 200000}}

Which is used in a jade file:

```
.item.range.range-positive
  input(type="range", min="{{filter.range.min}}", max="{{filter.range.max}}", step = "{{filter.range.step}}", ng-model="user_settings[filter.id].max", id= "handle")
```

Resetting this value works fine and puts the sliders to 0 and 200000. But on startup the sliders remain like this:

[image]

I did already understand that the sliders are first set when opening up the filters and before the DOM elements are nil. But when i open up the filters the DOM is evaluated but the value is set to 100 and not to the ng-models value.

I tried ng-init and reloading the scope but this just didn't work...

Is there anyway to create all the DOM elements on startup?

EDIT 1:

Here is the controller code that starts the application:

```
angular.module("starter.controllers", [])
  .controller "AppCtrl", ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, FilterService, $state) ->
    $scope.filters = FilterService.settings
    $scope.sort = FilterService.user_settings['sort']
    $scope.resetFilters = ->
      FilterService.resetFilters()
      $state.go('app.cars', {}, {reload: true})
    $scope.resetFilters()
```

Where resetFilters() calls following code:

initial value of user_settings:

```
user_settings = {sort: {attribute: 'offerPrice', direction: 'asc'}, price:{}, firstregistration:{}, power_ps:{},mileage:{}, emission:{}}
```

Code to resetFilters:

```
resetFilter: (filter) ->
    if filter.id in ['price', 'firstregistration', 'power_ps', 'mileage', 'emission']
      user_settings[filter.id].min = filter.range.min
      user_settings[filter.id].max = filter.range.max
    else
      delete user_settings[filter.id]

  resetFilters: ->
    console.log(user_settings)
    for filter_name, user_setting of user_settings
      if filter_name == 'sort'
        continue
      @resetFilter(@find(filter_name))
```

And the filter object contains the min and max values hardcoded.

Hope that helps to clarify...

Comment: have you tried initializing your object in controller?

Comment: @NIMESH If you mean the "user-settings" they are initialized on startup. Or am I getting you wrong there?

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Comment: yes sure, it's just a little tricky because the project has gotten a little complex. :)

Comment: For any readers trying to implement the range slider, you may find this question I asked valuable, especially since it has a working example. http://stackoverflow.com/q/42605685/5797593 Good luck!